# How to prefix 'N' for the parameters in a store procedure for a unicode strings

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, unicode

How to prefix 'N' for the parameters in a store procedure for a unicode  strings in c#, alternatively i am using the same procedure for the non unicode also. i need to append it only for the unicode ones kindly help.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to prefix `N` for parameters. This is only required for literals. Just make sure your stored procedure and ADO.NET parameters are of Unicode type (`nvarchar` or whatever).